# Hover styles are not having any effect

Tags: html, css

I want to use a hover tag for links in an unordered list, but when using hover after "a:" nothing happens It doesn't change color from white. Absolute beginner so any help appreciated.

I've looked at my HTML but can't seem to find anything wrong with it.

CSS:

```
header a: hover{
color: #cccccc;
font-weight: bold;
```

HTML:

```
<header>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="branding">
                <h1><span class="highlight">Acme</span> Web Design</h1>
            </div> 
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: There should be no space between your colon and hover.  voting to close as simple typographical error

Answer (score 2):

Perfect Code.. just remove extra space from CSS code and add a closing curly brace.

i.e.

```css
header a:hover{ color: #cccccc; font-weight: bold;}
```

```css
header a:hover{ color: #cccccc; font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="branding">
                <h1><span class="highlight">Acme</span> Web Design</h1>
            </div> 
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: @Pete Noted! :)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but questions like this honestly should be closed (there's even a perfect "Close" reason exactly for this type of problem!).  In the future, I'd encourage you to comment and close rather than produce an answer for a simply typographical error.

Comment: Ah I knew it would be something simple. All sorted, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
header a:hover{
  color: #cccccc;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Be carefull of what and how you type... After a and : should not be a space so a:hover and then you need closing semicolon on the end of your hover css.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but questions like this honestly should be closed (there's even a perfect "Close" reason exactly for this type of problem!).  In the future, I'd encourage you to comment and close rather than produce an answer for a simply typographical error.

Comment: @cale_b ah right! im kinda new in using this as "helper" so i dont really know all the functions! my bad :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have a space after :

The correct form is

`header a:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
  font-weight: bold;
}`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but questions like this honestly should be closed (there's even a perfect "Close" reason exactly for this type of problem!).  In the future, I'd encourage you to comment and close rather than produce an answer for a simply typographical error.

Comment: Thanks, all sorted :)